# xunit Assert.NotNull() does not play nicely with C# nullable types

Tags: xunit, nullable-reference-types

```
Assert.NotNull(res);
Assert.Equal(1, res.Foo); // CS8602 warning here
```

I'm using xunit.assert 2.4.1, .NET 6.0, VS 2022.

When "Ctrl+Click" navigating to the [Assert.NotNull()](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/43e3e208a597bc1a4c77f2665f39f98e7401c157/NullAsserts.cs) source code I can see it defined as

```
public static void NotNull(object @object)
```

while I was actually expecting to see

```
public static void NotNull([NotNull] object? @object)
```

From the xunit source code one can see that nullable flavour of methods are used only when `XUNIT_NULLABLE` conditional compilation variable is enabled. Can it be that nuget downloaded "non-nullable" version of the xunit.assert package? How can we force a "nullable" version (built with the `XUNIT_NULLABLE` defined)?

Comment: It’s nothing to do with XUnit. The C# compiler is telling you that at this point the value can still be null.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker, I think you misunderstood my question. For sure C# compiler generates the warning, but it does this because `Assert.NotNull()` does not prevent the compiler from telling the warning. You can create a custom NotNull() method `private void NotNull([NotNull] object? @object) {}` and use it to silence the compiler, so why cannot NUnit `Assert.NotNull()` do the same? And actually it can, please follow the link I've shared in the question and maybe you'll get my question.

Comment: It's coming as a part of v3.
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2011

I presume that the nuget package is compiled without the flag set so we don't have that ability yet.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, xunit 2.4.2 has been released and Assert.NotNull() plays nicely with C# nullable types!!

The following code is the implementation of [`NotNull` method in xunit.assert 2.4.2](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/58a59628853ed7a63895945fdac7984a92da2343/NullAsserts.cs#L23).

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Verifies that an object reference is not null.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="object">The object to be validated</param>
        /// <exception cref="NotNullException">Thrown when the object reference is null</exception>
#if XUNIT_NULLABLE
        public static void NotNull([NotNull] object? @object)
#else
        public static void NotNull(object @object)
#endif
        {
            if (@object == null)
                throw new NotNullException();
        }
```

Comment: I still get a warning on subsequent usages of of the object passed to `Assert.NotNull`

Comment: @PaulWheeler what version of `xunit` NuGet package do you use?

Comment: 2.4.2 with .Net 6.0 and C# 10. I have a nullable dynamic variable `dynamic? test = ...` and I pass it to `Assert.NotNull(test)` but I still get warnings on subsequent lines like `Assert.NotNull(test.member)`. I don't think it's an xunit issue per se because the same happens when I write my own version of `Assert.NotNull` the only way I can get it to work is with a generic function that returns the same type as it's argument and is decorated with `[return: NotNull]` in that case `test = MyAssertNotNull(test);` resolves the warnings.

Comment: My issue seems to be specific to using `dynamic?` It works fine for `Object?` thanks.